# sufficient condition for symmetry of Hessian matrix

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

From my knowledge of math, I know that one sufficient condition for the Hessian matrix to be symmetric(or resp. Hemitian) is the second order partial derivatives are continuous at the point concerned. But the book below gives no such continuity condition, how can this be true?
[image]

Comment: Differentiability is a much stronger condition than partial differentiability. The second derivative, if it exists [at an interior point of the domain], is symmetric. If the second derivative exists, the Hesse matrix is the matrix of the second derivative, hence symmetric. Continuity of the second order partial derivatives is a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for the existence of the second derivative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiability is a much stronger condition than partial differentiability.

The second derivative, if it exists [at an interior point of the domain], is symmetric. That is basically the content of Theorem 4.

If the second derivative exists at some point, the Hesse matrix at that point is the matrix of the second derivative, hence symmetric. Just like if the first derivative exists, its matrix is the matrix of the partial derivatives.

Continuity of the second order partial derivatives [at an interior point] is a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for the existence of the second derivative, and thus by transitivity for the symmetry of the Hesse matrix.

Comment: Can you explain why twice differentiability implies the continuity of the second order partial derivatives? thanks.

Comment: It doesn't. Continuity of the second partial derivatives is a strong condition that _implies_ for example the symmetry of the Hesse matrix. It is not implied by differentiability. Even the existence of the second derivative does not imply that the second partial derivatives are continuous at that point.

Comment: OK, then why many texts are talking about the continuity condition(the so called Schwarz's theorem)  rather than the simpler differentiability condition? I am confused here.

Comment: The differentiability condition is not really "simpler". If the (second) partial derivatives are not continuous at a point, then differentiability at that point is not easy to show, generally. Continuity of the partial derivatives is easier to check, and most of the functions one actually encounters have either that, or aren't twice differentiable, so the more general criterion is in practice rarely needed.